# Calculate % Change in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos

Is it possible to calculate a percentage change in a Cognos Report?

Currently, I have a crosstab that has years as the columns and widgets in the rows with a calculation of total revenue.  I am looking to calculate the annual % increase.  New to Cognos, but I could accomplish this using other tools.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think (I'm new to COGNOS as well) that you need to perform a calculation to do this. You'll need to divide the dataobjects to get it, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer to your question but perhaps it will help others who see it.

It's kind of annoying, but it can be done.  If you have one Query which uses an input parameter to select the year, perhaps it is a filter that says [Year] = ?YearPrompt?, then you can make a second Query which uses the filter [Year] = ?YearPrompt? - 1.  Then, you can join these two queries, and the third query (made by joining the first two) will have both this year's revenue, and last year's revenue, available to it for a calculation, such as what the percent change is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a query calculation item as one of the columns and in it you take Year2 - Year1(You can choose the exact columns you already have in the report using the Data Items tab when you are making the query calc) Also make sure you make this query calc a % in its format.